# Can export `csv` file from query in Clickhouse to s3? (only sharing)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, clickhouse

Get error timeout when try query in Clickhouse with large data. So I try query then export `csv` file and upload it to S3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Can do that.

The first ensure `s3_create_new_file_on_insert=1` in current Clickhouse database. Else can run. *Need permission to execute below script.*

```sql
SET s3_create_new_file_on_insert = 1
```

Example:

```sql
INSERT INTO FUNCTION s3('https://...naws.com/my.csv', 'KEY', 'SECRET')
SELECT user_id, name
FROM db.users
WHERE application_id =2
```

More info

- https://medium.com/datadenys/working-with-s3-files-directly-from-clickhouse-7db330af7875
- https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/s3/